# How do I change date format of Mon May 09 15:02:40 Asia/Kolkata 2016 to Mon May 09 15:02:40 IST 2016?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am getting a date from database in form of  Mon May 09 15:02:40 Asia/Kolkata 2016, I have to change it to Mon May 09 15:02:40 IST 2016. This is the formatter I am using to change other dates to Mon May 09 15:02:40 IST 2016.

```
 public static Timestamp convertStringToTimestamp(String date, String format){
        Timestamp timeStamp = null;
        java.util.Date time = null;
        if(date!=null){
            final SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat(format);
            final SimpleDateFormat sdf1= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
            try {
                time= sdf.parse(date);
                timeStamp = new Timestamp(sdf1.parse(sdf1.format(time)).getTime());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return timeStamp;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that ` Asia/Kolkata` is a timezone recognized by Java.  You might want to consider exporting from your database in a different format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a `java.sql.Timestamp`, this class object does not contain time zones, just the time and date.

If you want to output the three-letter acronym for a time zone (IST in your case), the format you should put in your `SimpleDateFormat` is simply `z` when you export it to a String.  However, be advised that this is lost when you parse it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8, you can try this.

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ZonedDateTimePipeTest {

    public static String formatWithResolveZoneIdToZoneNameJava8(String text) {
        // create global variable
        DateTimeFormatter in = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd H:mm:ss VV yyyy");
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(text, in);

        // create global variable
        DateTimeFormatter out = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd H:mm:ss z yyyy");
        // See for meaning of formatter symbols:
        // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html
        return out.format(zonedDateTime);
    }

    @Test
    public void conversion() throws Exception {
        String in = "Mon May 09 15:02:40 Asia/Kolkata 2016";
        String out = "Mon May 09 15:02:40 IST 2016";
        assertThat(formatWithResolveZoneIdToZoneNameJava8(in), is(out));
    }

}
```